# ValueError: math domain error - Black-Scholes Option Valuation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am writing a program to calculate the price of a Call Option explicitly using the Black-Scholes formula under the necessary conditions. I am getting an error when I run my code.

I am not sure what is causing it. Please, any and all help is very greatly appreciated. Here is my code thus far:

```
    ## This program is to perform an explicit Black-Scholes hedge using the formula:
##
## If a stock has a constant volatility of 18% and constant drift of 8%, with 
## continuously compounded interest rates constant at 6%, what is the value of
## an option to buy the stock for $25 in two years time, given a current stock
## price of $20?
##
## The description fits the Black-Scholes conditions. Thus, using s = 20, k = $25,
## sigma = 0.18, r = 0.06, and t= 2, we can calculate V_0 = $1.221. We will verify
## that this result is correct:
##
import numpy as np
from math import exp, log
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
s = 20 # current stock price
k = 25 #strike price of the option in dollars
sigma = 0.18 # constant volatility
r = 0.06 # constant interest rate
T = 2 # expiry date of contract, 2 years time

def V(s,T):
    return s * norm.cdf( (log(s / k) + (r + 0.5 * pow(sigma,2)) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T)) ) 
    - k * exp(-r * T) * norm.cdf(  (log(s / k) + (r - 0.5 * pow(sigma,2.0)) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T)) )

V_0 = V(s,T) # the value of our option at time t=0 is the same at expiry T

print V_0
```

This is what I get when I run my code: "ValueError: math domain error " and it points to the line where I return a value for the function I defined. Thanks!

Comment: Usually you get that error when you're taking a log of a negative number; check all your values to make sure you're using the right domain for each function

Comment: `log( s / k) = log( 0.8 )`, so I don't think that's quite it. Thank you though

Comment: It could be that one of the other functions is receiving an input that is out of their domain. Square roots of negative numbers (although it doesn't look like you have any) would also throw that error. I'm not sure about `norm.cdf` in the `scipy` package, but that may have some domain restrictions as well that you could maybe check out?

Comment: Okay, I will look out for that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log(s/k)` is throwing the error. Even though 20/25 = 0.8, since they are both integers, 20/25 evaluates to 0, and `log(0)` throws the error. Convert s or k or both to a float, and that should solve your problem

Comment: You can also put the following at the top of your script: `from __future__ import division`.  This will change Python's division semantics to those used in Python 3, where integer division doesn't happen unless you use the `//` operator.